# Number of specific associations for model in RoR

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

So I have a model `Doctor` and each doctor has many `appointments` and each appointment in its turn has it's `date` (as a datetime column).

I need to show a list of, let's say 30 doctors, and for each doctor, I need to show the number of appoinments he or she had on the 1st of June so I wonder how I could do that?

The best option I can come up with is to use nested SQL like this:

```
SELECT doctors.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) from appointments a WHERE a.date = 01.06.2014 AND a.doctor_id = doctors.id) as appointments_number FROM doctors;
```

(I know that the date is not filled correctly but I am too lazy to google the right way, it doesnt matter)

So, is there an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by all columns of the `doctors` table you want to select and add an count

```
SELECT d.id, d.name, count(a.id) as appointments
from FROM doctors d
join appointments a on a.doctor_id = d.id
WHERE a.date = '2014-06-01'
group by d.id, d.name
```

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would be to use the scope from the Appointment model:

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :for_date, -> (date) { where(date: date) }
end

Doctor.includes(:appointments).merge(Appointment.for_date()).count
```

Comment: The same problem as with the Pavan's answer

Comment: then just add `.count` at the end, it would only get a count from the db

Comment: I am not sure but I think that if add count to the end of the query, it will simply count the number of doctors, which is not what I need

Comment: not, if you call count on the ActiveRecord::Relation object, you make a `COUNT` sql query.

You can try this by calling `Doctor.includes(:appointments).merge(Appointment.for_date()).count.to_sql` in your rails console